# Drawing a line between two percentage points in Raphael JS

Tags: javascript, raphael

I'm trying to draw a path between two circles that are positioned based on percentage.
The reason they're positioned like this is that I scale the paper and want to maintain their locations.

This works well with the circles, but when I try to draw a path like this:

```
paper.path("M55% 70%L25% 20%")
```

All I get is:

```
Error: Problem parsing d="M,0,0"
```

How do I got about this?

Also, is there a way to get an element's percentage location without manually calculating it?

Thanks!

**Update:**

I ended up resolving my issue, but in a pretty manual, workaroundy way:

```
var canvasX = $('#worldmap svg').width() / 100;
var canvasY = $('#worldmap svg').height() / 100;
mapCanvas.path("M" + Math.floor(parseFloat(from.attr("cx")) * canvasX) + " "
        + Math.floor(parseFloat(from.attr("cy")) * canvasY) + "L"
        + Math.floor(parseFloat(to.attr("cx")) * canvasX) + " "
        + Math.floor(parseFloat(to.attr("cy")) * canvasY));
```

Needless to say, this isn't great.

Comment: How are you drawing the circles more exactly?

Comment: paper.circle('50%','50%',20);

Answer (score 1):

There's no indication in the SVG [PathData specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathData) that this kind of syntax is allowed. Actually I'm a bit surprised that it's allowed for something like the center of a circle...but I guess you're right.
However if you perform a scale the locations will not remain fixed, as you can see in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PUg8r/